# Sort image in Event Menu desc. I want the latest image at the top when I add a new image. I want it sort by desc not asc. this is my code:-

Tags: php, html

I want the latest image at the top when I add a new image at Event Menu. I want it sort by desc not asc.

this is my PHP code:-

```
    <div class="post-slider">
        <h1 class="slider-title">Event</h1>


        <?php foreach ($event as $key => $single): ?>
            
            <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL."/assets/events/".$single['photo']; ?>"  alt="Paris" style="width:60%;"> <br><br>
            
                <?php endforeach; ?>                

    
        <!--footer is here point to footer.php-->   
        <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/includes/footer.php"); ?>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        
        <!-- Slick Carousel -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Custom script -->
        <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>    
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can write order by in your query which is fetching records from database.

Comment: did you var_dump data retrieve from sql to check it is sorted in desc order ?

Comment: I already write it at SQL part (order by id desc) but still not functioning well.

Comment: function getPublishedEvents()
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT e.*, u.username FROM events AS e JOIN users AS u ON e.user_id=u.id WHERE e.published=? ORDER BY id DESC";

    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['published' => 1]);
    $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $records;


}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_reverse() returns a new array. (See [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).) So you either need to store the new array first or just use function within the declaration of your for loop.

```
<?php 
    $input = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    foreach (array_reverse($input) as $value) {
        echo $value."\n";
    }
?>
```

your output will be.

```
c
b
a
```

so according to your code

```
<?php foreach (array_reverse($event) as $key => $single): ?>
            
            <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL."/assets/events/".$single['photo']; ?>"  alt="Paris" style="width:60%;"> <br><br>
            
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thankyou for helping me. I gain new knowledge. Really appreciate it.

Comment: your problem resolved ?

Comment: yeah it is resolved.